# What synths and pads are those, and where to find?

Tags: synthesizer, ambience, production, replication

I've been listening to a modern (not EDM, but not acoustic as well) band, and I'm pretty amazed by their sound quality. I'd like to know what library I need, and which is best to achieve those sounds.

I'll put the link to the songs below, comment and ask about the tones I'm looking for. Anything you guys can tell will help me.

[OH WONDER - DRIVE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_w5jPT8LMF0)

1- The song starts with a Piano? Or is that a pad?

2- Ambience pads that appear mainly before the chorus.

3- Some kind of synth, kinda funny, panned right in the chorus (what's that?)

4- What's responsible for the low frequencies? Is there a bass over there?

5- Instrument at 2:46 that sounds like pad or so, panned left.

[OH WONDER - WITHOUT YOU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLAhRiUeJ8E)

1- Instrument that comes in at 0.45, panned left.

2- Low Synth that comes in at 2.34.

3- During the whole song, is there a bass synth?

That's it. I'm looking for a Library that contains these kind of tones. Thank's a lot.

Comment: You can make this kind of pads easily with some sine or square oscillators. Add some reverb, a little delay and a compressor/limiter if needed.

Comment: In the future, please give specific times in the video rather than "start of the song" and "before the chorus."

Comment: You need s software synthesizer and need to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The question of "what library do they come from" is nearly impossible to answer, since there are thousands of libraries out there and many of them overlap sonically.

I can't tell you every detail about every sound, but here's my general impression of how to replicate each one. It's all pretty meat and potatoes.

#### "Drive"

Instrument at 0:53: a synthesized Wurlitzer-style electric piano without tremolo. Probably best replicated with an FM synthesizer.

Right-panned synth at 1:48: a filtered organ with jittery vibrato and slow amplitude modulation.

Left-panned percussive instrument at 2:46: a marimba, or maybe a triangle or sine wave with a percussive envelope.

#### "Without You"

Left-panned synth at 0:45: square wave with a low-pass filter.

Bass at 2:34: low saw oscillator with a flanger or phaser.

Comment: You're right, I've edited accordingly